solana.pump scam coin $onei
I recently swapped some solana for a new .pump coin $onei
this coin was within 5 minutes of creation and after it had significantly profited I tried to swap back to SOL to collect my profits.
The activity of the coin then vanished from the DEX, jup.ag showed an error that "the route did not exist" and my money vanished (along with everyone elses I assume).
Is this a new scam or exploit happening on solana with pump coins or has anyone else experienced something similar?
Thanks,
Christian
